# Create a new array and merge

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

Is there a function in javascript or with underscore.js to create a new array with new values in objects ?
I'd like first to rename the values of my objects : year : "AllYears" and fruit :"AllFruits"

```
MyArray1 = [{year: "2013", fruit: "banana", quantity: 1},{year: "2014", fruit: "orange", quantity: 1},{year: "2014", fruit: "banana", quantity: 2}]
```

I'd like to create a new MyArray2 with new values and CONCAT with MyArray1

```
MyArray2  = [{year: "AllYear", fruit: "AllFruits", quantity: 1},{year: "AllYear", fruit: "AllFruits", quantity: 1},{year: "AllYear", fruit: "AllFruits", quantity: 2}]
```

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean "Is there a function in javascript or with underscore.js to create a new array ?" You created a new array like this: `MyArray1 = [{year: "2013", fruit: "banana", quantity: 1},{year: "2014", fruit: "orange", quantity: 1},{year: "2014", fruit: "banana", quantity: 2}]`

Comment: I'd like to rename the values of my objects : year : "AllYears" and fruit :"AllFruits"

Comment: you can traverse the array and change the values

Comment: What do you mean by "merge with `MyArray1`"?

Comment: sorry I 'd mean "concat" and not "merge"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of Underscore's `_.map` to create new array elements, and `_.extend` to copy and modify objects.

```
Array2 = _.map(Array1, function(elt) {
  return _.extend({}, elt, { year: "AllYear", fruit: "AllFruit" });
});
```

Note that to change the values, we don't want to do this directly, because it would change the values in `Array1`, so we need to make a copy of each object, which we have done with Underscore's `_.extend`, specifying the new values at the same time.

Comment: Finally I have a problem in Array2 :  when I select  the keys > values are 0

Comment: @observatoire I don't understand your comment, please clarify.

Comment: to torazaburo :  my Result is null `var Result= _.pluck(_.where(rows, {Year: "AllYear", Fruit: "AllFruit"}), Quantity) ;
//console.log(Result) >> Array[ ]`

Comment: What is `Quantity`? Did you mean `'quantity'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try just pushing MyArray1 to MyArray2:

```
MyArray2.push(MyArray1);
```

Comment: That will not add the elements of `MyArray1` to `MyArray2`, instead `MyArray2` will have the whole `MyArray1` as an element.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/map) or [`Array.prototype.forEach`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/foreach) and edit the values.

Comment: That would change the values of the objects in `Array1`.

Comment: That's somehow what he wants, 'rename the values of my objects', see comment on question.